# Unable to configure passenger and nginx for rails app deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger

I am deploying a rails app on VPS with CentOS. I have installed passenger with `gem install passenger`. And to install nginx I have used `rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module`.

In the nginx config file i have set:

```
server { 
        listen       80; 
        server_name  my-ip-address;  

       location / { 
            root   /home/deploy/repos/application-name/public; 
            passenger_enabled on; 
            rails_env production;  
        }
        ...
}
```

When I execute `sudo service nginx status` I get following:

```
nginx (pid 21015 21014) is running...
```

which shows nginx is running.

But I am getting `This webpage is not available` on browser.

Even I get the same result when I put on the rails server in the development mode with `rails s` and try to check in the browser with `my-ip-address:3000`

Can anyone help with what might be the issue?

When I run the command `passenger-config restart-app` the result is:

```
Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications
```

I need a suggestion on whether this is the problem with the nginx or passenger?

One more question is-

If my passenger is not installed correctly but nginx is installed correctly then would I be able to see the "welcome to nginx page"?

**Update:**

I tried running `passenger start -p 3000 -d -e production` by which passenger serves in the background. Now if I do `passenger-status` I get two instances of passenger out of which one says `Phusion Passenger is currently not serving any applications` and the other one shows like:

```
Version : 5.0.21
Date    : 2016-01-16 10:42:42 +0530
Instance: feOajf7V (nginx/1.8.0 Phusion_Passenger/5.0.21)

----------- General information -----------
Max pool size : 6
App groups    : 1
Processes     : 1
Requests in top-level queue : 0

----------- Application groups -----------
/home/deploy/repos/application-name/public (production):
  App root: /home/deploy/repos/application-name
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 22003   Sessions: 0       Processed: 0       Uptime: 4m 17s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 36M     Last used: 4m 17s ago
```

And if I run `passenger-config restart-app` I get result as:

```
Please select the application to restart.
 ‣   /home/deploy/repos/application-name/public (production)
     Cancel
```

Does this mean passenger is working correctly? But i see `webpage not available` in the browser.

Comment: Give this one a thorough read once, you'll get the hang of it:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-rails-apps-using-passenger-with-nginx-on-centos-6-5

Comment: Sorry I have not mentioned in the question but I have followed the same article for installing nginx and passenger and included the nginx management script also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't run `passenger` in your project's directory.
In the **root** directory of your project type:

```
passenger start -p <port>
```

where `<port>` is the port on which you'd like to run your app (ex: 8000).

**UPDATE**

According the updates in your question and the comments below, the problem doesn't seem to reside in the configuration of nginx or passenger. Since you try accessing your server not locally but with the real ip of your VPS, there's a chance that the ports in question aren't open. You can check if so [here.](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/)

Comment: I have updated my question with the results I got by following your suggestion. Still not working. can it be issue with nginx?

Comment: Sorry for responding you so late, but may I ask what do you enter in the address bar of your browser?

Comment: I just enter IPAddress in the browser.

Comment: Ok, I see where's the problem. You have to enter the IP **and** the port, i.e. 127.0.0.1:3000 or just localhost:3000

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I started standalone passenger I tried with port like you mentioned but with nginx I was trying just my IPAddress. I have mentioned in the question earlier that `Even I get the same result when I put on the rails server in the development mode with rails s and try to check in the browser with my-ip-address:3000`

Comment: `my-ip-address` is your localhost (something like 127.0.0.1) or the real one?

Comment: No the real one. On VPS I ran `rails s` for my application just to try. And I also tried the one you suggested. For that too I ran the VPS-IP-Address:3000.

Comment: As I see the problem doesn't come from passenger or nginx. I'd suggest checking whether ports 80 and 3000 on your VPS are open: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: Done, happy that I helped you :)

Comment: how exactly do we open the port.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no guru but in my (working ;) ) installation I have:

```
keepalive_timeout 10;
passenger_enabled on;
root /var/www/org/current/public;
```

In the *server block*, not the location block. Hope it helps.

And a quick scout of the documentation tells me the same:
https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/deploy/ruby/

I don't know if this will fix it for you, as getting nginx and passenger working I recall is a bit fiddly, and I use Chef, but this should help.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried that too but got same 'webpage is not available'.